# How did Persian words arrive in English?

Tags: etymology, british-english, subcontinental-english

Some Indian words which have entered modern English, such as 'bazaar' and 'cummerbund', are of Persian origin. So it seems they have completed a journey from Persia to Western India to present-day United Kingdom. How did they get from Persia to India? Was this due to the migration of Zoroastrians? And were there special linkages between the Parsees (descendants of the Zoroastrians) and the Westerners?

Comment: They also could have come from the Mughal empire, which was influenced by Persian culture.

Comment: In fact, given that *chador* is one of these words, my guess is that the words came through the Mughal empire ... *chador* is a word that is more likely to have been used by Muslims than by Zoroastrians.

Comment: It is true that some Persian words have arrived in English via India. But some wordsn have arrived by intractions between Roman and Sassanide empires. The word bazar aside from Persia-India-England journey, has arrived with another route: Persian-Latin (Roman Empire)-Italian-English.

Comment: @ Name The OED does have an entry for c1340, which refers to a Genoese name for market being Bazarra. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: @sw2 Yes, My point is that a word may has arrived in English by several ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the Wikipedia article “[List of English words of Persian origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Persian_origin)” answers that question.

- During the Achaemenid invasion of the Indus Valley, India was invaded by Persia, leading to mixing culture.
  I believe Persian rule over India was a major cause of Persian and Indian words mixing.
- The Persian English words also came through British Colonialism, because some people in India during British Colonial times spoke Persian.

Other Persian influence includes:

- The Persians influenced the Greek, which in turned influenced English.
- Persians also influenced the English through Ottoman Turk and Moorish-Christian culture.

Persians generally indirectly influenced English with the use of intermediary languages.

Comment: The similarity of vocabulary between Persian and Indian are not borrowings but come from well before, sorta just like Greek and Latin, a common past language heritage but also a common contemporary culture.

Answer (score 2):

Persian was official and court language of India in [Mughal Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mughal_Empire).
see also  [Persians_in_the_Mughal_Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persians_in_the_Mughal_Empire)

Answer (score -1):

All the answers posted so far are good, but there is another deep ancient similarity between English and Persian words as follows. If you Google "*avesta cognates*" there is a website: http://www.avesta.org/cognates.htm with a chart of 75 Avestan words similar to English words.

Likewise if you type: "Dictionary of most common avesta words" interestingly, you will find avestan words that are very similar to today's English terms. For example, year (*yare*), arm (*arema*), you (*yuzh*), he (*he*), we (*vae*), fresh (*frasha*), win (*van*), three (*thri*), gape (*gapa*), path (*pathan*), now (*nû*), not (*nôit*) ... and many more. The similarities are mind-boggling , especially considering the distance between Iran and England.

These are very similar, and makes me feel that in ancient times there had been a real migration of Iranians to the west and finally to England. I once read somewhere that ancient migration started from north India to Iran and then to other western parts of the euro-asian continents. For the last 4 years I have a video posted on *youtube* [83 Persian Words common with other Indo-Europeans](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuDSzgAkdyo)  there is now about 262 words. For example, the Scottish Gaelic words for numbers 8 and 80 are respectively *ocht* and *ochtad*, in Persian they are called *hasht* and *hashtad*! How many "tad" similarities are there at the end of those words!